# How to change the logo size for different screen sizes in Outlook and Gmail

Tags: html, outlook, gmail

How to change the logo size for different screen sizes in Outlook and Gmail. For a screen width of 760px, the size of the logo should be width: 175px, height: 25px. Thanks for help :)

``` <html> <head> <meta charset='UTF-8'> <title></title> </head> <body style="background-color: #FAFAFA; padding: 30px;"> <table style="padding: 15px; background-color: #FFF; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; margin-bottom: 20px; width: 700px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"> <tr> <td style="margin-top: 20px;"> <img style="width: 350px; height:50px" src="``https://dev.dms-suite.com/static/media/logo-light.78ae4dc9.png``" alt="Logo" /> </td> </tr> </table> </body> </html> ```

I have no idea how to implement it. Thanks!